# всплытие переменных после import

Tags: javascript, импорт

Есть ли всплытие переменной var (и соотв-но не всплытие const, let) при ее экспорте из файла? 
Т.е. когда мы принимаем import variable from './moduls/init' и эта переменная в файле из которого мы импортируем объявлена через var(var variable = ...)? 
Или же при компиляции бабель сам импортирует их вначало кода?

Comment: приведи пример кода о чем ты говоришь. Модули изолированы друг от друга, поэтому переменные объявленные внутри одного модуля не могут всплывать в другом модуле

Comment: Plugin.prototype.init = initModul;</br>import initModul from './moduls/init';  Вот так все работает, получается что видно значение до импорта... хотелось понять механизм

Comment: Добавь пример кода в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К началу выполнения модуля все его зависимости должны быть загружены и выполнены.

Поэтому, в принципе, не важно место где указан `import`. Важно, чтобы не было объявлено одноименных переменных на уровне `import`.

```
console.log(a)
import a from 'a'; // OK
```

---

```
var a = 10; // let ; const - то же самое поведение
import a from 'a'; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

---

```
import a from 'a'; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
var a = 10; // let ; const - то же самое поведение
```

Стоит так же отметить, что ошибка будет выведена *до* исполнения модуля, следовательно не будет выполнен не только код текущего модуля, но так же не будут выполнены его зависимости.